# AudioSystem randomly closing while crossfading 2 MediaPlayer objects

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Where do I begin?! I've spent a ton of time trying to debug this, to no avail.  I've hit a deadend and would really appreciate some help.

My scenario: I'm trying to make a media player for Android that will crossfade each song.  I've created 2 MediaPlayer objects (playerA & playerB) where playerA is the player that plays the 'first song'.  The ideal scenario would be that if a user hits the next button via the MediaPlayerController OR the song is 10 seconds from finishing - playerA begins fading OUT at the exact same time playerB loads a song, begins playing it, and fades IN the volume - giving you the crossfade effect.

Though I have gotten this to work, and perfectly I must say, I'm having random failures.  I'd define the failure as: the next song (played via the 'other' player) you will hear nothing.  I've checked on the actual status of the failing/quiet player while it's exhibiting this behavior and .isPlayer()=true and playerA.getDuration() - playerA.getCurrentPosition() is counting so MediaPlayer thinks its actually playing - but again you can't hear anything.

I've tried a million things and different ways, but again, can't get it to NOT randomly 'break'.  The ways I've tried to do the 'repeating code' to get it to fade out and in are via a separate thread that uses a UI handle that sits in the service start method, I tried using a TimerTask, and I tried using a postDelayed handler with many different delays (handler_crossfadeA.postDelayed(runnable_crossfadeA,500);)

Some technical details: I've created each playerA & playerB via a singleton that extends MediaPlayer (amongst a million other things) so I only get 1 instance of each, my main activity binds to a MusicService that plays the sound, I'm using the Android L/5 API, I'm testing on the Nexus 5

So I've tracked it down, by extremely minimizing my code, to this as causing the problem (again, it's random - but typically happens within 5 songs in, but I did get some code to last up to 20 songs): Given playerA begins when the app first starts, then transitions the next song to playerB, then 10 seconds after playerB is playing playerA stops Android's AudioPlayer get's upset (ioConfigChanged() error) and disconnects the audio hardware (error from audio_hw_primary).  Ultimately I was able to reproduce this rather easily by setting a postDelayed handler 500ms after after playerB started to stop playerA (eliminating all my volume in and out adjustments, etc).  I even tried moving around my stop() & reset() code to different methods including inside my crossfade method, inside my playSong() method, in the onPrepare() method.

**To summarize:**

- I can get this to work fine if I remove any 'sleep' (or waiting) after I set playerB's setDataSource -> start() in the MediaPlaye's onPrepared().
- Whereas this breaks it: playerA is playing -> hit next song button -> playerB sets data source -> call prepare() (prepareAsync() has same behavior) -> onPrepared() calls start() -> sleep 500ms or longer -> stop() & reset() (or just reset() playerA.  So again, it's resetting playerA AFTER playerB is already playing that's breaking this.  I know my situation seems slightly odd, but I really feel Android should have no problem handling this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603752/android-mediaplayer-crossfade is related, but in no way the same question.

---

Though I have a ton of code that wouldn't fit in this post, after stripping it down for troubleshooting purposes, here's what I generally have (apologies in advance if I'm missing something relevant):

Part of service start method:

`handler_crossfadeA = new Handler();
guiHandler= new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

init() method called on service startup for each player:

```
    playerA.setAudioSessionId(11);
    playerA.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    playerA.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    playerA.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    playerA.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    playerA.setOnErrorListener(this);
```

Part of playSong() method

`try{ playerA.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri); } catch(Exception e){  }
try{ playerA.prepare(); } catch (IllegalStateException e) { e.printStackTrace();} catch (IOException e) {  }`

Part of onPrepared() method:

`playerA.start(); //or call playerB.start if its not the next player
call crossfade method`

Part of crossfade method, different variation for each player:

`handler_crossfadeA_iteration=0;
            runnable_crossfadeA = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    playerA.stop();
                    playerA.reset();
                }
};
handler_crossfadeA.postDelayed(runnable_crossfadeA,500); //500ms isnt ideal but i got it to still break this way`

---

Most relevant error that I think is causing this:

- **AudioSystem - ioConfigChanged() closing unknown output!**
- I looked up this error in the Android c++ code but couldn't find any useful clues

Following related errors:

- audio_hw_primary - out_set_parameters: enter: usecae(3: compress-offload-playback) kvpairs:  exiting=1
- offload_visualizer - thread exit
- audio_hw_primary - disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: compress-offload-playback
- audio_hw_primary - offload_thread_loop: compress handle is null

At a minimum I'm posting so I hope I can share my experience with others and get all of this info in one location.

Full screenshot of errors:
[image]